# Any way to find out what US Customs & Border Protection has in their database on me?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I travel from the US to Canada occasionally (about once per year on average) with my family. We are all US citizens and travel with US passports. Every time we re-enter the United States, I am given extra scrutiny.

Most recently, we used an automated check-in procedure at the airport. These are terminals where you scan your passport & fill out a customs declaration online and it prints a receipt which you take to the customs agent. When I got my receipt, it had a big "X" printed on it and we were directed to a line to talk to an agent.

In the past, I've had questions directed at me or my family: "Have you ever been to New York?", "Do you own any firearms?", and once "Where is your daddy?" directed at my then 4 year old son. The agents also seem to examine my photo & my face more closely than the other members of my family.

We get through customs OK, but it gives me a some anxiety. I suspect that there's someone out there with the same name (I have a pretty common name) who is on a "no fly" list or something.

My question is this: is there any way to find out what they're looking for when they scan my passport & see my name? Like a Freedom of Information request or something? I know I could/should ask when I'm in the line, but as I said, it makes me pretty anxious.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to get at *why* you're being selected, but [DHS's Redress program](http://www.dhs.gov/one-stop-travelers-redress-process) should fix it in the future (assuming it's just a name issue and you're not actually the person they're concerned about).

Comment: Check the Interpol website for wanted people, search for your name. I have found 29 people with a similar names to mine! (http://www.interpol.int/notice/search/wanted)

Comment: Quick reminder: It should be assumed that if you request your file, and one didn't exist, one will promptly be created.

Comment: @keshlam So you just have to try again... easy! ;)

Comment: @keshlam: please don't write unhelpful stuff on serious questions

Comment: @smci Actually, at least within the agency I work, a file is required to be created for every FOIA request.

Comment: @CGCampbell - that seems reasonable. You can, after all, make FOIA requests for FOIA requests.

Comment: @CGCampbell: unless that goes back to CBP agents and is something that would influence their actions at the border, it's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @smci The point is, to ask the CBP for a release of data on yourself under FOIA, if you don't have a file, you will have a file made. Of course, it appears that this user HAS a file already... or is being mistaken for someone who does. (and my basic point was you chastised keshlam unfairly, in my opinion.) His comment was a fair comment, clarifying a point that the OP may not have considered.

Comment: Randomly found this. Curious if you ever got anything from them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check out [Read Your Own DHS Travel Dossier](https://web.archive.org/web/20080326200832/http://unsecureflight.com/request.html) (archive.org). The *.doc files don't work anymore but the *.txt files do. It's basically a template letter requesting the information they have on you, pursuant to the Privacy Act.

Check out [Criminal History Summary Checks](https://www.fbi.gov/services/cjis/identity-history-summary-checks) on fbi.gov as well. That's FBI / DOJ and not TSA / DHS, but it might give you some insight none-the-less. [Get My FBI File](http://www.getmyfbifile.com/faq.html) has additional information.

Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

It might be very difficult to get off one of those lists though. There's a very recent court ruling, regarding a case where someone was placed on a nofly list by accident and wanted to get off that list, which was way more complicated then it sounds. [The court file](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/1115178-2014-04-15-full-ibrahim-order-with-highlighted.html) may hold some leads for you. Also see [this news article](http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20140417/17265226950/us-has-secret-exception-to-reasonable-suspicion-putting-people-no-fly-list.shtml) discussing up the problems.