# How can I find out if I'm wanted in Turkey?

Tags: online-resources, legal, borders, turkey

Say that I want to travel to a foreign country, but it's possible I am wanted by the authorities there*. To find out if this is the case, I could just go, and see if I get arrested at the airport, but that's far from ideal. I'd much rather know it before departing. How? Can a lawyer find this out for me? Or an embassy? or through an online resource? And won't asking about it prompt the authorities to look into me, and put me on the wanted list if I'm not yet on it?
If the information is available, how reliable is it?

Note: I would only need to know for a single specific country before traveling there. I don't need a table of all countries in the world with a yea or nay.

Update: Alright, if this question can't be answered generally (not even a few general guidelines), I'm specifically interested in Turkey.

*I am not currently wanted anywhere (that I know of), but in the future I may be indirectly associated with a company in the online gambling business, which is not legal everywhere. I have no control over where that company chooses to operate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to find out whether you're wanted in a particular country - but _anywhere_ may be a stretch, especially in some countries with less than strict adherence to human rights acts.  As for your association with a gambling business, that would depend on your association and also on what that business does.  I have worked for a gambling business for a couple of years and have travelled to the USA while doing so - with no problem.

Comment: By 'wanted' do you mean that there is a pending arrest warrant for you? Because you later refer to 'indirectly associated'.  Both of these can be causes for detention upon arrival. Please clarify.

Comment: @GayotFow In the end I would want to know, can I go to that country safely, or would I get in trouble?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom, that's fine. Scope your question down to just the UK and EEA and I'll put in an answer. You won't like the answer, but I'll put it in anyway because you have a very interesting question.

Comment: Euh, can't you query for a *Visa*? I think most countries will refuse a visa to wanted criminals (or perhaps the indeed will offer it in the hope you show up)?

Comment: If you break the law of a country, there is a very good chance you'll face troubles when you go back there, if you could get out f the country in first place. Unless you are an international criminal (say, wanted by the Interpol), they can run a background check. Such queries take some time, and as far as I know, immigration officers only refer to their country's databases only at the airport. Cops from you home country can always arrest you from any country (I can remember a few news items).

Comment: Which country? This is pretty broad - and the solution or method to find out will likely differ from country to country.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26303/22140

Comment: If its serious enough, you could end up on the [interpol website](http://www.interpol.int/notice/search/wanted) and any country party to interpol would be obligated to detain you. That's the closest I can come up with with respect to "anywhere".

Comment: @BurhanKhalid What countries do with Interpol notices is up to them, some of them do detain people with red notices as a matter of course but there is no general obligation to do so just because you are a member of Interpol.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom If you know where to look (e.g. which tribunal/prosecutor's office to contact), a lawyer could indeed make some inquiries but generally you can't easily know. Systems like the SIS even have “discreet surveillance or specific checks” alerts to require covert observation and they certainly won't tell you about those.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom would you be interested in accepting my answer below WITHOUT upvoting it? so I can get a very difficult hat :)

Answer (score 5):

Turkish police does not have a page for wanted people, so no online resources by the Turkish government.

The only online resource which might give you this information is the [interpol](http://interpol.int), Turkey is a member of interpol and they should send information about wanted people to the interpol, especially those who do not reside in Turkey. Interpol has a page for wanted people, you can search a specific country and/or a name.

Other than that, your best option is hiring a lawyer in Turkey to help you with more accurate data.

Comment: +1 Might be useful to add that countries only report a small number of all outstanding warrants/wanted people to Interpol.